# install manually my word add-in VSTO (Ribbon)? built with c#

Tags: c#, add-in

Is it possible to manually install my word add-in?
Visual Studio is preparing an installation file for word add-in and it worked great but i want to build more complex installation file. if i knew how to do it manually it would be very easy to build my own installer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure its possible.

If you use Visual Studio 2013, you have two common options to deploy your addin.
One is to use publishing, also known as, Click-Once, this basically does all the dirty work for you, and leaves you with an executable that helps you deploy it on your target machines by simply double clicking it.

[image: VSTO Addin Deployment - Click Once]

The other method is to use the InstallShield.
Go to File > Add > New Project > Other Project Types > Setup and Deployment > Installshield ...

You most likely do not have install shield installed, so once you try to choose that project a webpage will pop up, asking you to register (quickly and freely) to download and install Install-Shield limited edition - do it, its quite fast.

When its done, you may add a setup project to your solution.
now this part is very user-friendly, and allows you to build a custom install to your liking.
Notice that the free "limited edition" as they call it, gives you quite a lot of features, so it should be enough for light weight word addin.

Now, placing the focus on the Word Addin, the whole idea of the install is to place about 4 registry values into the deployed machine to point to the dll you compiled, and describe it.

You can find all the information you need by following microsoft's step-by-step guide on deploying an addin. its very fun and simple. really!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx

Good Luck !