# Installed Office word add-in is not working

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, add-in

I created a word add-in and now want to use it on another com.
I have installed and set in options/add-ins/. It shows that my add-in is active but from the menu-bar I can't find add-ins.
Please help me how can I do?

I developed with C# and publish into setup.exe and .vsto file. So install with them on other coms.

Comment: I just tried like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930439/install-manually-my-word-add-in-vsto-ribbon-built-with-c-sharp here. But it is not working

Comment: I'm afraid this question is not clear. What I understand is that you've created a VSTO Add-in for Word. Beyond that, things are not clear. Could you use the [edit] link to add screen shots of "set in optinos/add-ins" AND what you mean by "but from the menu-bar I can't find add-ins"?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Custom Ribbon is activated:

```
File -> Options -> Customize Ribbon -> Main Tabs
```

Your Custom Ribbon option should be checked

Answer (score 0):

By default, if a VSTO Add-in attempts to manipulate the Microsoft Office user interface (UI) and fails, no error message is displayed. However, you can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom ribbon does not appear, or why a ribbon appears but no controls appear.

To show VSTO Add-in user interface errors you need:

1. Start the application.
2. Click the `File` tab.
3. Click `Options`.
4. In the categories pane, click `Advanced`.
5. In the details pane, select `Show VSTO Add-in user interface errors`, and then click `OK`.

See [How to: Show Add-in user interface errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-show-add-in-user-interface-errors?view=vs-2019) for more information.